# What uses Linux "application memory"?

Tags: process, memory, ls

Just for fun, I wanted to watch what `ls -lR /` does to my "buffers" memory on a Linux system. As expected, the value increased. But I noticed that the "application memory" (i.e. "used" - (buffers + cache)) also increased, and it did not drop back down after the command was finished.

So I tested it again after a reboot and with as few applications running as possible (in case some other application was using the memory and I did not notice). I recorded `top -b -n 1` output before and afterwards:

```
$ free -m
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          3879        413       3466          1         63        232
-/+ buffers/cache:        117       3762
Swap:         7059          0       7059

$ top -b -n 1
top - 19:33:36 up 11 min,  1 user,  load average: 0,00, 0,02, 0,05
Tasks: 130 total,   1 running, 129 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s):  0,3 us,  0,2 sy,  0,0 ni, 97,9 id,  1,5 wa,  0,0 hi,  0,0 si,  0,0 st
KiB Mem:   3972908 total,   423356 used,  3549552 free,    65308 buffers
KiB Swap:  7229324 total,        0 used,  7229324 free.   238424 cached Mem
(process list omitted)

$ ls -lR /
(output omitted)

$ free -m
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          3879       1293       2586          1        315        252
-/+ buffers/cache:        725       3154
Swap:         7059          0       7059

$ top -b -n 1
top - 19:36:19 up 14 min,  1 user,  load average: 0,33, 0,25, 0,13
Tasks: 130 total,   1 running, 129 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s):  0,4 us,  2,2 sy,  0,0 ni, 95,5 id,  1,8 wa,  0,0 hi,  0,0 si,  0,0 st
KiB Mem:   3972908 total,  1324492 used,  2648416 free,   322580 buffers
KiB Swap:  7229324 total,        0 used,  7229324 free.   258976 cached Mem
(process list omitted)
```

The process list in stayed exactly the same (except for some changes in the `TIME+` column and the `top` process itself, of course), showing that no process is actually using the extra half Gigabyte of memory. So my question is: what uses this memory and will it be freed eventually? Also, will the same thing also happen when I use my system for a long time and access the file system a lot?

Comment: I had a similar problem a while back, endless fascination. I think the problem was a bug in the calculation of the various classes of used memory. (I think there is another class of buffer/cache type memory.) On my system everything worked fine, if the system needed it then it was freed. If just always over reported on application memory, and possibly under reported one of the other types. The problem went away, when I upgraded my kernel. (what is the output of `uname -a`?

Comment: This happens on `Linux mypc 3.16.0-28-generic #38-Ubuntu SMP Fri Dec 12 17:37:40 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux` and also on my a virtual machine with `Linux debian-vm 3.2.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.2.63-2+deb7u2 x86_64 GNU/Linux`.

Comment: For me it was a problem on a pae kernel, it seems to be OK now I have upgraded to 64bit kernel.